# How to create JavaFX tree sub nodes

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to create JavaFX with sub nodes. I managed to create very simple tree:

```
public class SQLBrowser extends Application {

    //////
    public List<ConnectionsListObj> connListObj = new ArrayList<>();

    public class ConnectionsListObj {

        private String connectionName;
        private String dbgwName;
        private String tableName;

        public ConnectionsListObj(String connectionName, String dbgwName, String tableName) {

            this.connectionName = connectionName;
            this.dbgwName = dbgwName;
            this.tableName = tableName;

        }

        public String getConnectionName() {
            return connectionName;
        }

        public void setConnectionName(String connectionName) {
            this.connectionName = connectionName;
        }

        public String getDbgwName() {
            return dbgwName;
        }

        public void setDbgwName(String dbgwName) {
            this.dbgwName = dbgwName;
        }

        public String getTableName() {
            return tableName;
        }

        public void setTableName(String tableName) {
            this.tableName = tableName;
        }
    }
    ///// -------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Button Sample");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(190);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setLayoutX(20);
        vbox.setLayoutY(20);

        ////////// Insert data

        connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW1", "Table 1"));
        connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW1", "Table 2"));
        connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW2", "Table 3"));
        connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW2", "Table 4"));

        //////////  Display data

        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Connection Name");
        root.setExpanded(true);

        for (ConnectionsListObj connection : connListObj) {
            // Add subnode DBGW name
            String DBName = connection.dbgwName;

            root.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(connection.dbgwName));

        }

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(root);

        /////////

        vbox.getChildren().add(treeView);
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

But I don't have a idea how to create sub nodes into the nodes. I want to have One connection with several DBGW and every DBGW with list of tables generated from the ArrayList.

```
connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW1", "Table 1"));
connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW1", "Table 2"));
connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW2", "Table 3"));
connListObj.add(new ConnectionsListObj("Connection 1", "DBGW2", "Table 4"));
```

But how I can create a loop which iterates into the ArrayList and generates the three.

P.S. I Updated the code this way:

```
TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Connection Name");
        root.setExpanded(true);

        for (ConnectionsListObj connection : connListObj) {
            // Add subnode DBGW name
            String DBName = connection.dbgwName;

            TreeItem sb;

            root.getChildren().addAll(sb = new TreeItem<>(connection.dbgwName));

            //if (DBName.equals(oldDBName)) {

            sb.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(connection.tableName));

            //}

        }

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(root);
```

Get this result:

[image]

How to sort the `tables` based on the `DBGW`.

Comment: when i get this right, you want one `dbgw1` item and then `table1` and `table2` as children and not two `dbgw1`.

Answer (score 1):

The `TreeItem` has a list of its Children. You have to add the child nodes to it:

```
parentNode.getChildren().add(yourNode);
```

See [Using JavaFX UI Controls - Tree View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm) for a complete example.

Comment: Yes I managed to create sub nodes. But now the problem is how I can sort them properly?

Comment: @PeterPenzov they are sorted in the order in which you are adding them.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the TreeItems sorted when we add/remove TreeItems (preferbaly till depth 3) in javafx2?  I can see some SortedList in javafx8 but sadly moving to jdk8 is not feasible for me.